# If $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$, what is $f(2x)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$. My guess is that $f(2x)=\ln(2x+2)$. But, I cannot find a way to explain this in english.

For example, if I say, "the function $f$ is evaluated for two times each value of $x$, this implies that $f(2x)=\ln(2x+1)$."

An even better attempt is to say, "the function $f$ takes each $x$ coordinate, adds one to it then takes the natural logarithm of that. So, when the function $f$ for $2x$, every single $x$ value that has had a one added to it is now multiplied by two."

But, the latter description, even if true (I don't know), is not really a proper mathematical explanation. It's merely a description to a fact that I am memorising to get past an exam.

This question arose when I was studying the Maclaurin series, where when we have a function $\ln(1+2x)$, we substitute the $2x$ into the standard series of $\ln(x+1)$, so I immediately thought about this being $f(2x)$!

Comment: Consider a simpler example, if $f(x) = x+1$, what should be $f(2x)$?

Comment: It is $\ln(2x+1)$. You are evaluating the function at $2x$. So you replace $x$ by $2x$.

Answer (score 9):

$f(x) = \ln(x + 1)$ means this:

"The function $f$ evaluated at $\color{red}{\text{thing}}$ is equal to $\ln(\color{red}{\text{thing}} + 1)$."

---

So if $\color{red}{\text{thing}}$ is just $\color{red}x$, then $f(\color{red}x) = \ln(\color{red}x+1)$.

---

If $\color{red}{\text{thing}}$ is $\color{red}{2x}$,  then $f(\color{red}{2x}) = \ln(\color{red}{2x} + 1)$.

Comment: Hats off tilper, especially the thing about the thing... and all the stuff :,) Say I have a function sin(ax+b). This video (examsolutions.net/tutorials/trigonometric-graphs-exam-quest‌​ions/…) states that when considering the transformation) states that this is equivalent to a stretch of scale factor of 1/b and a translation of b/a. This is why I used a complex example here, to mirror this trigonometric function. How would you explain the apparent discrepancy in this trigonometric graph compared with your explanation?

Comment: @Mathematician, thanks.  Link was cut off so I can't see it but I'm not sure what the discrepancy would be.

Comment: If f(x)=sin(x), f(x+(b/a))=sin(x+(b/a))=g(x). Therefore, g(ax)=sin(ax+(b/a)). As can be seen, the factor 'a' applied to the x doesn't apply to the translation factor. But, the video immediately factorises the 'a' from ax+b in the sin(ax+b)=sin(a(x+(b/a))) which is not equal to sin(ax+(b/a)) as I have shown. So, what transformations logic applies here?

Comment: @Mathematician, sorry, I'm still not sure I follow.  What two things are not equal that you are expecting to be equal?  If $f(x) = \sin x$, then $f(ax) = \sin ax = g(x)$ and $f(ax + b) = \sin(ax + b) = \sin(a(x + \frac ba)) = g(x + \frac ba)$.  Transformation logic is universally the same:  $f(x-c)$ shifts the graph of $f(x)$ to the right by $c$ units if $c > 0$ and left by $-c$ units if $c < 0$.  $f(ax)$ horizontally stretches the graph of $f(x)$ by a factor of $\frac 1a$ if $0 < a < 1$ and horizontally compresses it by a factor of $a$ if $a > 1$.

Comment: The fact that you have to use "thing" instead of $x$ shows that symbolism is a big deterrent to the understanding mathematics. Unfortunately the modern trend favors too much symbolism instead of natural language (like "thjng").

Comment: http://www.examsolutions.net/tutorials/trigonometric-graphs-exam-questions/?level=A-Level&board=Edexcel&module=C2&topic=1321

Comment: The above is the video, but I think I need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

### A Reminder of What Composition Means

Recall what function composition means.  Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be two functions, then $(f\circ g)(x)$ is the function you get by first evaluating $g(x)$, then evaluating $f$ at that number.  I.e. $$(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$$

Example: Let $f(x) = 4\sin(x)$ and $g(x) = x^2$, then $$(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(x^2) = 4\sin(x^2)\quad \color{blue}{=4\sin(g(x))}$$ and $$(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(4\sin(x)) = (4\sin(x))^2 = 16\sin^2(x)\quad \color{blue}{=(f(x))^2}$$

So basically for $(f\circ g)(x)$, you replace the $x$ everywhere in your prescription of $f$ with $g(x)$ and likewise to evaluate $(g\circ f)(x)$, you replace the $x$ everywhere in your prescription of $g$ with $f(x)$.

---

### Solution

In your exercise, $\ln(x+1)$ is the composition of two functions: $\ln(x)$ and $h(x) = x+1$.  I.e. $\ln(x+1) = (\ln\circ\ h)(x)$.  In this form, maybe it's easier to see that if $f(x) = (\ln\circ\ h)(x)$, then

$$f(2x) = (\ln\circ\ h)(2x) = \ln(h(2x)) = \ln(2x+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$f(2x) = \ln(2x + 1)$$

If you have some function $g$, then you get $g(2x)$ from $g(x)$ by performing the substitution $x \mapsto (2x)$. Note use of parentheses.

Comment: Say I have a function sin(ax+b). This video (http://www.examsolutions.net/tutorials/trigonometric-graphs-exam-questions/?level=A-Level&board=Edexcel&module=C2&topic=1321) states that when considering the transformation) states that this is equivalent to a stretch of scale factor of 1/b and a translation of b/a. This is why I used a complex example here, to mirror this trigonometric function. How would you explain the apparent discrepancy in this trigonometric graph compared with your explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Think it this way : $f(2x)$ is nothing else than shrinking the graph of $f(x)$ by a factor of $2$, along the x-axis. The shrinking is longitudinal, hence the point located at $(0,f(0))$ must not change. Hence everything, except the $(x)$ must remain the same as putting $x=0$ must result in the value of function. Thus, **only** $(x)$ must be replaced by $(2x)$, nothing else. For example 
$$f(x)=x+3\implies f(2x)=(2x)+3$$

Comment: Say I have a function sin(ax+b). This video (examsolutions.net/tutorials/trigonometric-graphs-exam-quest‌​ions/…) states that when considering the transformation) states that this is equivalent to a stretch of scale factor of 1/b and a translation of b/a. This is why I used a complex example here, to mirror this trigonometric function. How would you explain the apparent discrepancy in this trigonometric graph compared with your explanation?